# Nesting ajax requests makes code hard to read

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I usually like to organize my code so that one function fires a bunch of other
functions, like this:

```
/**
 * GET MESSAGES:
 */
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/messages',
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(messages) {
      if (messages.length > 0) {
        keyedMessages = keyFork(messages);
        reversedMessages = reverse(keyedMessages);
        crushedMessages = crush(reversedMessages);
        getFriendships(messages, crushedMessages);
      }
      mail.template.airmail();
    }
  });
});
```

However, if I need to do a second Ajax request inside one of the nested 
functions I can't return the data because of the scope of the Ajax request
and it makes my code inconsistent and hard to follow, sort of broken up all over the place.  For example, if one of the functions 
invoked above fires a second Ajax request for friendships anything I write 
after that will be broken from the communication chain due to the request and it seems impossible to return anything:

```
/**
 * GET FRIENDSHIPS:
 */
function getFriendships(messages, crushedMessages) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'friendships',
    method: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(friendships) {
      addKey(crushedMessages, friendships);
      filteredCrushedMessages = filterUnconfirmedSender(crushedMessages);
      filteredCrushedMessages.forEach(function(filteredCrushedMessage) {
        mail.sidebar.builder.messengers(filteredCrushedMessage);
      });
      mail.snailMail.onload();
    }
  });
}
```

If I try to return the data it doesn't work.  Consequently I'll have to 
continue invoking functions inside the nested request, every time I need to make another nested ajax request it breaks the chain. This makes my 
code very hard to read.  Are there any solutions to this problem or is
code that uses Ajax requests just hard to read?

Comment: Well you can use global variables that can be accessed in any function. Instead of returning anything, you just change its value on one side and read it on the other.

Comment: I'll consider that.  I've been trying out different recipes for having neater, cleaner code.  Next app I write will need to use some other pattern.  The one I'm using now pretty much sucks.

Comment: Look into promises, they can help you structure multiple callbacks after eachother. But for storing data, yeah, use some kind of namespaced data model to write data to you'll reuse later on.

Comment: It won't be a popular answer, but setting your child ajax requests to 'async:false' will allow you to keep the linear/functional code flow that you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the data on a DOM element, then use [jQuery Custom Events](https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events) to get it done.

There's even support for passing arguments to your event handler:
https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/#naming-custom-events

Answer (score 0):

> If I try to return the data it doesn't work.

Not appear jQuery promise returned from either function at Question ?

Try utilizing `return` statement , `$.when.apply(this, arrayOfPromises)` to return array of jQuery promise object from `getFriendships`

```
function getFriendships(messages, crushedMessages) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'friendships',
    method: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(friendships) {
      addKey(crushedMessages, friendships);
      filteredCrushedMessages = filterUnconfirmedSender(crushedMessages);          
      mail.snailMail.onload();
      return $.when.apply($
        , filteredCrushedMessages.map(function(filteredCrushedMessage) {
            return mail.sidebar.builder.messengers(filteredCrushedMessage);
          })
      );
    }
  });
}
// e.g., 
getFriendships(messages, crushedMessages)
.then(function success() {
  console.log(arguments)
}, function err(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(errorThrown)
})
```